# Basic redux-saga, getting back undefined data

Tags: redux, axios, action, redux-saga

So I'm currently learning Redux-Saga and need a little help.

I've received the action and the watcherSaga has caught it and sent it to the workerSaga which runs a function with axios.get to receive data. In the function, I can actually console.log the data and return it, however when it gets back to the saga, the data is undefined. Here are some screenshots, please let me know if you need any other information.

[image: Here is my saga that receives the action and calls displayBlogs which then calls getBlogsSaga]

[image: here is the getBlogsSaga function that gets the data from the API call and returns it]

[image: lastly, here is the console log showing getBlogsSaga actually has the data but when it returns to the saga, it is undefined.]

Comment: The three images are: 1. The action being received, displayBlogs running and calling getBlogsSaga. 2. getBlogsSaga uses axios.get to get the data which shows up in the console log, and returns this data. 3. My data is undefined, even though I've returned it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `return await axios.get(API_URL)`.

E.g.

`rootSaga.js`:

```js
import { call, put, takeEvery } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { getBlogsSaga } from './getBlogSaga';

const BLOGS = {
  LOAD: 'BLOGS_LOAD',
};

function setBlogs(payload) {
  return {
    type: 'SET_BLOGS',
    payload,
  };
}

function* displayBlogs() {
  const data = yield call(getBlogsSaga);
  console.log(data);
  yield put(setBlogs(data));
}

function* rootSaga() {
  yield takeEvery(BLOGS.LOAD, displayBlogs);
}

export { rootSaga, displayBlogs };
```

`getBlogSaga.ts`:

```js
const getBlogsSaga = async () => {
  return await Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    return [1, 2, 3];
  });
};
export { getBlogsSaga };
```

`rootSaga.test.ts`:

```js
import { displayBlogs } from './rootSaga';
import { runSaga } from 'redux-saga';

describe('63000691', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const dispatched: any[] = [];
    await runSaga(
      {
        dispatch: (action) => dispatched.push(action),
        getState: () => ({}),
      },
      displayBlogs,
    ).toPromise();
  });
});
```

test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/63000691/rootSaga.test.ts
  63000691
    ✓ should pass (16 ms)

  console.log
    [ 1, 2, 3 ]

      at src/stackoverflow/63000691/rootSaga.ts:17:11

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.235 s, estimated 3 s
```

Answer (score 0):

Your arrow function uses curly braces `{` so there is no implicit return. Either explicitly return `axios.get` (and incidentally since you are returning a promise there is no need to use `async/await`) or change to parens to take advantage of the explicit return.

```
const getBlogsSaga = async () => {
  return await axios.get(..
}
```

or

```
const getBlogsSaga = async () => (
  await axios.get(...
)
```